# Web scraping: update data like in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

All the articles about web scraping in Python I came across quoted BeautifulSoup and Selenium as the main tools to use to retrieve HTML and JavaScript content from a webpage.

However, I have not found a way to automatically update the data received from this same webpage without the need to send it a new request.

Is it impossible to do in Python what you would do with Google Chrome, that is, simply opening a webpage and looking at it being automatically updated by the host itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example, you can download elements of the DOM tree in a loop if the content is dynamically modified using JavaScript. You can also call your own JavaScript to perform a specific action. Alternatively, you can even write and upload your own browser plugin. In general, in selenium you can control the browser to a large extent, just like a normal user, without the need to refresh the page again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and informative comment ! Should I understand from it that the solution implies coding in JavaScript, or is there a way to do the same in Python with selenium ? In any case, would you have some ideas of the concepts I should look after to find concrete explanations about how to carry out this project ? Kind regards.

Comment: The easiest way is to observe the element using loops and react to changes. So just get the current state of the loop element and see what happens.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks a lot for your kind and useful answers ;-)

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please accept it. Thanks and good luck with selenium!